# TypeError: f.handler.apply is not a function

Tags: jquery, handler, typeerror

As you can read, here is my error:

> TypeError: f.handler.apply is not a function

I don't know how to figure it out and solve it except to remove the `helloK();`

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function helloK() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {

        $('#global-div').fullpage.destroy();

    } else {

        $('#global-div').fullpage.build();

        }
    }

    helloK();  // Checking when page load

    $(window).resize(function(){
        helloK(); // Checking to destroy or build when we resize browser
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `fullpage` initialised on the `#global-div` element before you try and `destroy()` it?

Comment: yes, I have the plugin called before my main js file. I have never got this error and I don't know how to solve it :/

Comment: Try `fullpage().destroy()` and `fullpage().build()` - note the additional brackets.

Comment: A new error is happening with this : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'build' of undefined